# Turn all traffic to Apache when IIS is off

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2012, iis

I have a dedicated server that works on Windows Server 2012. It hosts multiple websites using IIS. I have Apache sever installed on this server too. I need to know how to redirect all the traffic for all the hosted websites on IIS to a specific page or resource on the Apache while IIS is being off or paused? i.e a page with simple message tells that server is down instead of the default message of 404 not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want a load balancer in front of both. You can use apache load balancer (alb) serving on port 80. Setup IIS and apache web server on higher ports. Have the load balancer act as fail over not true load balancing. So alb listens on port 80 and any requests get proxied to IIS on a higher port (8181 for example). This way as soon as IIS is down alb will detect the fail and switch to apache web server running on another high port (8182 for example).

Apache is not the only software load balancer out there, you can use nginx to do the same work, or others. The concept is the same.

EDIT:

Here is an example of an nginx failover (active/passive) setup:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8181 fail_timeout=5s max_fails=3;
    server 127.0.0.1:8182 backup;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name whatevs.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

If the first backend (127.0.0.1:8181) fails 3 times (5s timeout), nginx will switch to the backup host (127.0.0.1:8182). Note that the IP can be the same or you use virtual ips, but the ports will have to be different if using the same ip.

Hope this helps :-)